# error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I am new to C# and .NET and trying to reuse a piece of code for purposes of a HTTP triggered Azure Function.

I am getting the above error message when trying to pass a variable "test" to "SerializeObject". SerializeObject expects an "object" but it appears of different type (HttpResponseMessage) so the below conversion (JsonConvert) does not work. Is there a way to convert a string to an object that HttpReponseMessage accepts?

```
// string test = "abcd";
 object test  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("abcd");
```

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
       {        
           Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") 
      };
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want  to achieve?

Comment: The error is not related to what you describe, you are returning `HttpResponseMessage` in a function that is actually declared to return `Mvc.IActionResult`, hence the compiler error.